# `[T]` cannot be formatted with the default formatter

Tags: rust

I am learning Rust through a *educationnal* project, where I wish to implement mathematical Matrices and Vectors. I am doing this for the sake of learning Rust.
I am having an issue displaying a slice of generic type in my Display function.

Here my Vector.rs file is as such:

```
use std::fmt;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Vector<'a, K> {
    data: &'a [K]
}

impl<'a, K> Vector<'a, K> {
    fn new(data: &'a [K]) -> Vector<'a, K> {
        Vector {
            data: data
        }
    }
    fn len(&self) -> usize {
        self.data.len()
    }
}

impl<'a, K> fmt::Display for Vector<'a, K>
where K: std::fmt::Display {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}", self.data)
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("Test File for Vectors");
    let mut v = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4];
    let my_v = Vector::new(&v);
}
```

When Compiling, I face the following error

```
error[E0277]: `[K]` doesn't implement `std::fmt::Display`
  --> Vector.rs:22:19
   |
22 |         write!(f, "{}", self.data)
   |                         ^^^^^^^^^ `[K]` cannot be formatted with the default formatter
   |
```

This error is saying I need to implement Display for the type `[K]` which I do not understand.
Here my type K is `f64` so the Display does exists, and I also added the line `where K: std::fmt::Display` to be certain that type K has the Display function.

Is what I am trying to do impossible ? Did I missunderstand slices ?
Thank you.

Comment: Arrays do not implement `Display` even if their contents do. Did you mean `write!(f, "{:?}", self.data)`?

Comment: It does indeed works, thank you, but I do not understand, isn't {:?}` for debug only ? Why would this work ? @mousetail

Comment: `Debug` shows the structure of a object, so it can be used on things like structs, arrays, vectors etc. `Display` is by default only implemented on scalar like strings and ints, or types where you implement it yourself. In general you implement only `Debug`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Display` is meant for the endusers, `Debug` is meant for the developers.

Usually, messages to endusers don't include representations of vectors, so `Vec`/`Slice` does not implement `Display`. They are only printable via `Debug`.

As your struct is actually meant to be displayed to the enduser, you need to implement `Display` for it yourself by actually serializing every element and then joining and formatting them the way you like.

For example, like this:

```
use std::fmt;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Vector<'a, K> {
    data: &'a [K],
}

impl<'a, K> Vector<'a, K> {
    fn new(data: &'a [K]) -> Vector<'a, K> {
        Vector { data: data }
    }
}

impl<'a, K> fmt::Display for Vector<'a, K>
where
    K: std::fmt::Display,
{
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        let formatted_elements = self
            .data
            .iter()
            .map(|el| format!("{}", el))
            .collect::<Vec<_>>();
        let elements = formatted_elements.join(", ");
        write!(f, "[{}]", elements)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let v = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4];
    let my_v = Vector::new(&v);
    println!("{}", my_v);
}
```

```
[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4]
```